# Cycle when merging two ListNodes

Tags: python, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This problem is from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/)

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode
# def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#   self.val = val
#   self.next = next
```

In my solution, if I do the following, I get an error that a cycle has been found in the ListNode:

```
elif (l1.val<l2.val): 
   sol = ListNode
   sol.val = l1.val
   sol.next = Solution.mergeTwoLists(self, l1.next, l2)
   return sol
```

Alternatively, if I define sol differently - as the following - the solution works:

```
elif (l1.val<l2.val): 
   sol = ListNode (val = l1.val)
   sol.next = Solution.mergeTwoLists(self, l1.next, l2)
   return sol
```

The difference is in the way that sol is initially defined.

I realize there are many ways to correctly solve this problem. However, I don't understand the fundamental difference between the two pieces of code above, particularly why one creates a cycle and the other doesn't. I would appreciate any insight!

Comment: `sol = ListNode` does not call the constructor. It assigns the function object to `sol`, so now `sol` is a function. No nodes are created. That's not what you want.

Comment: I consider this a typo and voted to close for that reason. If not, then certainly it's a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```py
sol = ListNode
```

You're not creating a new object of type `ListNode`, but instead creating a reference to the class definition itself. By adding the round brackets `ListNode()` you're **instantiating** this object. This let's you then interact with it by calling it's `.val` and `.next` properties.